# Rails 3: Sortable Columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sorting

I'm following Railscasts #228 in Rails 3.0.5 and ruby 1.9.2p180.

I have copied code near verbatim from the verbatim with the exception of changing the class name from Product to Player. I'm also skipping the last portion where Ryan adds arrows to denote the sort direction. I'm able to load the correct index page and see all of the desired URL's with the desired parameters (direction and sort), but nothing is actually happening on click. The URL is changing, but the page is not reloading.

Here is my code:

ApplicationHelper

```
  def sortable(column, title = nil)  
    title ||= column.titleize  
    direction = (column == params[:sort] && params[:direction] == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"  
    link_to title, :sort => column, :direction => direction  
  end
```

PlayersController

```
  def index
    @players = Player.order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction)
  end

  private

  def find_team
    session[:team] ||= Team.new
  end

  def sort_column  
    Player.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name_e"  
  end  

  def sort_direction  
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ?  params[:direction] : "asc"  
  end
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit: As requested, HTML code. You can see that the link for Position is currently desc, as I am at: http://localhost:3000/players?direction=asc&sort=abb_pos. However, no actual sorting has occurred for this column, or any other column.

```
<th><a href="/players?direction=asc&amp;sort=name_e">Name</a></th> 
<th><a href="/players?direction=asc&amp;sort=team_e">Team</a></th> 
<th><a href="/players?direction=desc&amp;sort=abb_pos">Position</a></th> 
<th><a href="/players?direction=asc&amp;sort=height">Height</a></th> 
<th><a href="/players?direction=asc&amp;sort=weight">Weight</a></th>
```

Comment: Could you provide some runtime html code with the links in it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I had the following code in my player model:

Player.rb

```
default_scope :order => 'name_e'
```

As a result, the SQL search generated looked like this:

```
SELECT `players`.* FROM `players` ORDER BY name_e, avg_points desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Nathan

I'd suggest doing this first thing:

```
def index
  order = sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction
  puts "-- order:'#{order}'"
  ...
end
```

Click the links and then look in server's console for that "--" output. Most probably there's a logical flaw somewhere that makes the actual compiled ORDER clause always be the same. Links themselves look perfectly okay. Unless there's a `#` character in the links somewhere, all clicks should work (i.e. the browser should reload the content).

As for the problem in general, there's a gem called [handles_sortable_columns](https://github.com/dadooda/handles_sortable_columns), which gets you sortable columns for no effort at all.

Alex

Comment: This is very odd. The exact same thing happens when I use handles_sortable_columns as well.